# What does a right caret at start of line in makefile do

Tags: makefile

I inherited a makefile that begins all lines in a target with the ">" right caret character. I have tried to research what this does and why it is there, but have not been able to find anything.

```
some-target:
>    echo "hello world"
>    cd /some/dir
>    echo "etc.."
```

Answer (score 3):

Check if your `makefile` has the following line anywhere:

```
.RECIPEPREFIX := >
```

this will override the default `tab` character for recipe prefix to `>`.

Refer to https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Variables.html for more information about `.RECIPEPREFIX` special variable.

Note, that `.RECIPEPREFIX` has been added in `GNU make` version `3.82`.

Comment: You were exactly right. Thanks for answering this.

Comment: If your question is answered please click the check mark next to the answer so it's marked as answered.